# Spaces in Assembly's name for pack URI

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, resourcedictionary

I have an assembly called `Core Library`(note the space `U+0020`) and I want to refer to the resources in that assembly using a `pack://` URI. I know that the pack URI scheme should give me something like:

```
pack://application:,,,/Core Library;component/Resources/...
```

How should I make  the CLR/WPF find my resources?

- Should I use `+` → `/...Core+Library;component/`,
- or should I use `%20` → `/...Core%20Library;component/`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to rename your assembly to remove the space.

Comment: I've heard/read somewhere, that pack URIs shouldn't have spaces in them. I am developing a project from the ground up and still many unimplemented parts that don't allow me to compile yet.

Comment: @CodeNaked, that sure takes me back to 8.3 names. Why didn't Microsoft consider names with spaces! Come on, it is the first printable character of ASCII! (At least I can use chars above 0x7F).

Comment: @Minustar: it is not a good practice to include spaces in executable names or DLL names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just did a quick test, included the space in the name as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Library 2;component/Test.xaml"/>
```

And it worked. Thus, I'd suggest your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: You were right! I couldn't test without writing further code; however, I created another project with spaces in the names of the assemblies, and these worked! Sorry to all, I feel like a fool when I ask a question about a problem that doesn't exist! Thanks again!

Comment: About the above comment. It worked as long as the reference is within the same DLL. A `ControlTemplate` couldn't be found because of a space.